# Making an incoming call broadcast receiver speak the caller's name

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to make an incoming call broadcast receiver, which can speak out the caller's name. I'd appreciate your help on how to use Text-To-Speech (TTS) to achieve this.

Comment: Added tag, improved punctuation, elaborated what TTS stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Add Receiver in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
   <receiver android:name=".IncomingCall">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Add Permission

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Create a **Listener**

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

                       // Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);


                       // state = 1 means when phone is ringing
          if (state == 1) {

             String msg = " New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
             int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(pcontext, msg, duration);
                            toast.show();

                      }
                }
          }
```

Add your **BroadCastReceiver**

```
    public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
               // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
                TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                //Create Listner
                MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

                // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
                tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
        }

    }

    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

            if (state == 1) {

                String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(pcontext, msg, duration);
                toast.show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```